# What response does ember.js/ember-data expect from a post request?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

Generally it is expected to not return any data from a post request. However, ember.js always thinks the promise was rejected and runs the then function (even though there were no errors on the server and everything was inserted as it's suppose to)

So I am assuming ember is looking for some data returned from the post request, maybe the entity that was created.

So question: What data does ember.js expect, how is it formatted?

Comment: What is the code used to send the request and the one used to receive the response?

Comment: What do you mean by code? Like the .save() and my onsuccess / on fail functions? Or the network request that is being sent? 

Does ember.js actually expect a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects the model back (with the id if it's a new record)